# Download a public file in Bitrise Workflow

Tags: file, curl, workflow, bitrise

I have my zip uploaded on Gofile, and using the direct download link I'm trying to use CURL in my step to download it on my build.

Even if the step work, the file is not totally donwloaded as I can't unzip it..

```
+ curl https://srv-store3.gofile.io/download/RIDfRD/xxxx.zip -o xxxx.zip
```

here is the command I used

I have no idea why this don't download. I also tried the "official" download step

Comment: Did you tried debug it using remote access? Because it can be related with path where you want to store that file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving the following error when trying to unzip it?

> End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
> a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
> latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
> the last disk(s) of this archive.

This means the zip file is corrupted. I was able to reproduce it with my own file. Go file is intended to be downloaded from the website not through curl.

I would recommend using a different service like https://gist.github.com and copying the raw file link and using that in the curl command.